# Три цвета фона расположенные под углом

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Как мне получить фон, похожий на этот образ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только 3 цвета, которые идут от верхнего угла, как солнечный луч.

Может быть, лучше использовать простой `PNG` или `SVG` для фонового изображения?

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30317427/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317427/three-colors-angled-background-color/30319613#30319613

Comment: Наверняка же градиентами можно?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ну такой "кривой" вариант на css с помощью `border`:

```css
.bg {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #16334a;
}

.bg:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 100vh solid #204158; 
  border-left: 70vw solid transparent;
}

.bg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 70vh solid #0a253e; 
  border-right: 100vw solid transparent;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  color: #ccc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In, impedit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_T, ну вот чтобы сходились лучи подправила (забыла про top =) ), а вот с пропорциями как раз и "криво" из-за относительных `vw` и `vh`

Answer (score 9):

### SVG

Это можно сделать с помощью `SVG`. Я использовал три `polygon`. Они  установлены на фоновое изображение. Или альтернативно их использовать `inline`, чтобы вы могли применить на них свойства `CSS`.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.triple {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
.triple:hover {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="triple" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <polygon fill="#dd2" points="0,0 100,0 0,60" />
  <polygon fill="#bb2" points="0,60 100,0 30,100 0,100 " />
  <polygon fill="#992" points="30,100 100,0 100,100" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30319613/7394871) от участника  [@Persijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3999748/persijn).</sub>

Answer (score 7):

И еще вариант с градиентами.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135.7deg, transparent 70vw, #000 70.1vw), linear-gradient(156.5deg, #ccc 40vw, #666 40.1vw);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_T, да это, видимо, опять "тайный поклонник" который последнее время всем минуса раздает ради забавы. Ответ как всегда отличный, от меня тоже + .

Comment: Так вам тоже? Я вчера писал свои предложения в чате по этому поводу )

Answer (score 6):

### CSS

Эффект может быть достигнут с помощью  использования псевдоэлементов и преобразований `CSS`.
Ниже приведен фрагмент кода.
Но я не думаю, что использование `CSS` является правильным вариантом для этого.
Лучше использовать PNG-изображение.
Фрагмент использует пару псевдоэлементов с разными цветами фона, скошенными (`skewed`) под требуемыми углами, для получения трехцветного эффекта.

```css
.bg {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bg:after,
.bg:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: right top;
}
.bg:before {
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
}
.bg:after {
  top: -100%;
  background: yellow;
  transform: skewY(-15deg);
}
span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Just for demo */
.bg:hover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg">
  <span>Some content inside</span>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30317703/7394871) от участника  [@Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry).</sub>

Answer (score 5):

`clip-path` (SVG-fallback для FF) и псевдоэлементы.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#clips {
  display: block;
  height:0;
  width:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
}

div:before, div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 0% 60%);
  clip-path: url(#clip1);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 0% 60%);
  background-color: #ccc;
}

div:before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 60% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 60%);
  clip-path: url(#clip2);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 60% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 60%);
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<svg id="clips">
  <defs>
    <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="clip1">
      <polygon points="0,0 1,0 0,0.6" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="clip2">
      <polygon points="1,0 0.6,1 0,1 0,.06" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_T сделал еще `<clipPath>` фоллбек с SVG для FF.

Answer (score 3):

Можно повернуть 2 белых полупрозрачных прямоугольника

```html
<svg viewbox="-250,0,250,150" style="background: steelblue;">
  <rect x=-500 height=150 width=500 fill=#fff4 transform=rotate(-22)></rect>
  <rect x=-500 height=150 width=500 fill=#fff4 transform=rotate(-44)></rect>
<svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Конический градиент просто создан для таких задач

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: conic-gradient(from 180deg at right top, #204158 55deg,#16334a  55deg, #16334a 70deg, #0a253e 70deg);
}
```